# Grammar of “In Meditations, Aurelius wrote about ways to live a Stoic life, asserting that humans should aim to live a virtuous life to be happy”

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, punctuation, modifiers, participles

Below: a photo of a learner's textbook exercise page with a reading passage about a Stoic Roman emperor, with punctuation issues – and a question about punctuation, with rejoinders. "A" (the first answer) is circled. There is a handwritten note that "asserting" translates to a synonym for "claim" and that it is a participle. "C" (the third answer) is crossed out with a note "hyphen".

[image]

> *In Meditations, Aurelius wrote about ways to live a Stoic **life,** **asserting** that humans should aim to live a virtuous life to be happy.*
>
>  
> Which choice completes the text so that it conforms to the conventions of Standard English?
>
> - A) life, asserting
> - B) life.  Asserting
> - C) life - asserting
> - D) life; asserting

I’m trying to learn from the text above. The bold part is the single,  correct answer to a quiz asking to pick an answer conforming to accord of Standard English. However, nothing’s explained to me why the sentence is inherently correct this way. Like, is the comma after “**life**” valid? And why? Thus, I get that “**asserting**” is a participle phrase, but what is the rest of the sentence then? What does “asserting” modify?

Comment: When he wrote about life, he was asserting virtue. "Asserting" modifies *wrote*. Since life was not doing the asserting, a little pause there helps the reader or listener separate it from "asserting."

Comment: Please note: a participle construction is often used instead of: and asserts that humans should aim to live a virtuous life to be happy. See? :) He loves donuts, eating them every day. He loves donuts and eats them every day. Same thing.

Comment: @TimR: I'd say the syntax is inherently ambiguous in both OP's and your example. The participial clauses can be parsed / understood as adverbially modifying the specific verb (***wrote*** or ***went***) OR as "whole sentence adverb" usages, modifying the entirety of the preceding assertion ***Aurelius wrote about ways to live a Stoic life*** or ***He went into the city***.

Comment: @TimR: I don't understand your distinction between "modifying" and "elaborating". (But please don't try to explain it to me, because if it's not obvious to me straight away, I'm never gonna be convinced it's a *useful* distinction! :)

Comment: @TimR: That ***dripping*** example looks like a perfectly normal adverbial modification of the verb ***came***. But I don't like your example, because the ***asserting*** clause doesn't meaningfully modify ***wrote*** - it goes off on a tangent that imho should perhaps have been attached with ***and asserted*** or similar.

Comment: Thanks and ignoring the content, could you bear in mind that Posting pictures of text, unaccompanied by actual text, is usually far less helpful then it seems? Considering the context, why would this not belong better to English Language Learners?

In any case, the pictured text doesn't look like something that makes the choices easy… though whether that'a a good or a bad thing depends on the students' progress.

Please, what language is that, between the pictured question and the given choices?

Comment: Participle phrases are a kind of adjective phrase. 'Asserting' modifies 'Marcus Aurelius'. See e.g. https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm

Comment: Here, 'asserting that humans should aim to live a virtuous life to be happy' is a parenthetical, tacking on information to the matrix sentence (the main clause 'In _Meditations_, Aurelius wrote about ways to live a Stoic life' (which would stand alone as a grammatical sentence). The paraphrase 'In _Meditations_, Aurelius wrote about ways to live a Stoic life: he asserted that humans should aim to live a virtuous life to be happy.' shows that the participle clause is an expansive/detailing adjunct. Both clauses refer to Aurelius as agent, but nuance the cited work as instrument.

Comment: On a purely pragmatic level, "asserting that humans should aim to live a virtuous life to be happy" isn't a sentence, so it can't follow a full stop, and some people would frown on a semicolon not followed by a full sentence (except in a list). A hyphen would be entirely inappropriate, but an em dash is almost as good as a comma, although it would be less common.

Comment: Marcus Aurelius was a Stoic philosopher. In "Meditations", Aurelius wrote about ways to live a Stoic life, asserting *[= in which he asserted]* that humans should aim to live a virtuous life to be happy.